# How to solve could not write code due to no disk space left?

Tags: cpanel

Our Whois subscription has unlimited disk usage or space, but I can not edit my code it prompts no disk left.

this image is on Cpanel Disk Usage Page
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zybYD.png)

it says here all are infinite
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WEPIE.png)

How to solve this issue it prompts no disk left